# Minimum rank of a multivariable Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, interpolation

Given $m\geq 1$, a multi-degree $\alpha = (a_1, \dots, a_m) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^m$, and an element of $x = (x_1, \dots, x_m) \in \mathbb{C}^m$, let’s create a row of a matrix by writing down all $(a_1+1) \cdots (a_m+1)$ monomials of degrees $\leq a_i$ in the $x_i$.

As an example, for $m=2$ and $\alpha = (1,2)$, we’d get the following row given an element $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2$:

$ ( x_1 x_2^2 \qquad x_2^2 \qquad x_1 x_2 \qquad x_2 \qquad x_1 \qquad 1). $

Choosing $A = (a_1+1) \cdots (a_m+1)$  distinct elements $x^1, \dots, x^A \in \mathbb{C}^m$, we can make a square matrix $M$ by designating a row for each $x^j = (x^j_1,\dots,x^j_m)$:

$ M := \begin{pmatrix} (x^1_1)^{a_1} \cdots (x^1_m)^{a_m} & \cdots & x^1_m & 1 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ (x^A_1)^{a_1} \cdots (x^A_m)^{a_m} & \cdots & x^A_m & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$

When $m=1$, this is just the degree $a+1$ Vandermonde matrix and the determinant is the product of differences of the entries $x^j$ (in particular, it is nonzero when we choose the $x^j \in \mathbb{C}$ to be distinct). Of course, we cannot expect to have such a description in general when $m>1$.

My question is this: can we guarantee that this matrix has some minimum rank, maybe $\min\{a_i\}$ or something similar growing with degree, simply by assuming the $x^j \in \mathbb{C}^m$ are distinct? That is, can we guarantee the first $\min\{a_i\}$ rows are linearly independent, or some similar result? Some very bad bounds seem possible, depending more on $m$ than on $\alpha$, but I know there is a general theory of interpolation which should be relevant to understanding this matrix.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the matrix displaying as you would like? As currently displayed, it's a single row which will always have rank 1 since it has a nonzero entry (the 1 in the final spot).

Comment: I was trying to avoid using too many indices—let me make it more clear in the question that this is a single row of the matrix, and we get a row for every choice of $x \in \mathbb{C}^m$.